# How to check which radio button is selected in group box radio button in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form control group box in an excel sheet in which I have multiple radio button and out of those only one button will be selected, I need to find out which button is selected using vba .I have written this code but it is not working and getting error that object does not support this property at the line "For Each button In buttonGroup.Controls". Please guide me with some way to achieve this.

```
Sub IdentifySelectedRadioButton()

    Dim buttonGroup As Object

    Dim button As Object

    ' Set the button group name
    

    Set buttonGroup = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Group Box 1").OLEFormat.Object
    

    ' Loop through each button in the group

    For Each button In buttonGroup.Controls

        ' Check if the button is selected

        If button.Value = True Then
 
            MsgBox "Selected radio button: " & button.Caption

            Exit Sub

        End If

    Next button

    ' If no button is selected

    MsgBox "No radio button selected."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA doesn't handle this situation very well. By searching through the values in the Watch window I was able to come up with this that seems to work

```
Public Sub demo()
    Dim buttonGroup As Object
    Dim button As Object
    
    ' Get the button group
    Set buttonGroup = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Group Box 1").OLEFormat.Object
    
    ' Loop through each control on the page
    For Each button In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        Dim b As OptionButton
        ' Check if the button is selected
        If button.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then
            Set b = button.OLEFormat.Object
            If b.Value = xlOn Then
                MsgBox "Selected radio button: " & b.Name & " , " & b.Text
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    
    Next button
    
    ' If no button is selected
    MsgBox "No radio button selected."
End Sub
```

Points to note

1. the value of an OptionButton is either xlOn or xlOff - not True/False
2. The actual optionButton properties are on the `button.OLEFormat.Object`
3. In the watch window the GroupBox for the variable `b` was set and I could see its name, but attempting to access it via code resulted in the same error.
4. I didn't pursue that problem so this scenario is limited to a single GroupBox on the sheet
5. The one I nearly forgot - the controls are on the sheet not contained in the groupbox

Whilst not entirely a satisfactory answer I hope this at least gives you some clues as to why you are suffering

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

'PUT THIS PUBLIC FUNCTION IN A MODULE
'------------------------------------------------
Public Function getSelectedOptionOfGroup(ws As Worksheet, group As String) As Object
   Dim ob As Object, sh As Shape

   For Each sh In ws.Shapes
      If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "OLEObject" Then
         Set ob = sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object
         If Not ob Is Nothing Then
            If TypeName(ob) = "OptionButton" Then
               If ob.GroupName = group And ob.value Then
                  Set getSelectedOptionOfGroup = ob
                  Exit Function
               End If
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Function


'PUT THIS BUTTON CLICK EVENT IN A SHEET module
-----------------------------------------------
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   Dim opt As Object
   Set opt = getSelectedOptionOfGroup(Me, "TEST_GROUP")
   If Not opt Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox (opt.Caption)
   End If
End Sub
```

[image]